# Что необходимо для создания веб хостинга для только одной CMS написанной на Ruby on Rails?

Tags: хостинг, ruby, hosting, ruby-on-rails

Поставленная задача: развернуть облачный хостинг с услугой доступа к CMS написанной на Ruby On Rails. Что бы каждый пользователь, который пользуется данным хостингом мог настроить и контролировать свою копию CMS, но только на "верхнем" уровне (настройка, пользователи, размер базы, дизайн и т.п.), без доступа к исходникам.

Что-то вроде мульти-wordpress, только организация "мульти" должна обеспечиваться панелью, а не самой CMS.

Какие системы лучше подойдут для frondend и backend? Что лучше подойдет для данной задачи OpenPanel(для RoR), Webmin или что-то другое? Что лучше прочесть в данном направление?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если у вас возникают такие вопросы, то мне кажется, что вам ещё рано этим заниматься.

Мало того, некоторые вопросы у вас так и не возникли:

- хранить ли данные в одной физической БД или класть всё по отдельности в контейнеры вместе с БД;
- как обеспечить обращение к нужной cms, если пользователь делает обращение через свой домен;
- как делать assets:precompile после загрузки новых CSS пользователем;
- как контролировать размер бд?
- как не дать одному приложению доступа до папки config другого, чтобы даже в теории не было доступа до другой БД;
- если субдомены, что делать с куками *.site.com?

Панель уж очень получается индивидуальная. Вы будете сайт писать, так и внедрите в него загрузку/редактор CSS'ок. Пользователи и настройки CMS управляются уже в самой CMS. Можно приделать сброс административного пароля CMS'ки через вашу панель.

UPD:
При деплое нового CMS - добавлять его в nginx virtual host, или как-то внутри разруливать, создавать нового пользователя, копировать приложение по образцу, создавать нового пользователя mysql, новую БД, прописывать это в config/database.yml, делать `rake db:create db:migrate db:seed`, последнее - для админского пароля, потом что там CMS требует для минимального наполнения запускать ещё. Что делать с перезапуском nginx так, чтобы на работоспособность остальных сайтов не повлияло - пока не ясно. Хранилище сессий - туда же в mysql. Вроде как всё. Ещё неплохо было бы sh/chef скриптов понаписать, чтобы если что пошло не так, то можно было бы новые сервера быстро поднимать. Ререзвное копирование, в том числе БД. Ну и повесить БД на отдельный хост без доступа по ssh с той машины, где приложения. Повесить haproxy, если машин будет несколько. И без ssh доступа снаружи до какой-либо из этих машин, только с какой-то хиленькой ssh proxy машины.

PS Расскажете потом, что у вас вышло.

Comment: Спасибо! В теме также стоит вопрос "Что лучше прочесть в данном направление?", что могли бы посоветовать?

Comment: @Dima Kodnik Стоить прочесть rails tutorial, linux administration, доку по mysql и можно в путь.

Comment: Знание linux, mysql - имеются. Отсутствует понимание организации хостинга, "концепция" организации данной задачи.